# Issue with storing percentages in a long

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program for class that reads a list of hours worked annually from a .txt file, assigns/reads (A little fuzzy on the proper terminology :)) them into an array, and then calculates overages and prints them.

When I run, console output is as follows:

```
Employee 1 worked 1600 hours, an under-run of 160 or 0%
Employee 3 worked 1680 hours, an under-run of 80 or 0%
```

Why are the percentages zero?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Calculator 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
  {

  try{

      String filePathString=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What is the file path?");  

      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\hello.txt");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
      String strLine;
      int counter = 0;
      long[] Array = new long[5];   


      //Read File Line By Line
      while (counter <= 4)

        {
            strLine = br.readLine();
            Array[counter] = Long.parseLong(strLine); 
            OverageUnderage(Array[counter], counter);
            counter = counter + 1;
        }

  //Close the input stream
  in.close();

    }

  catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  }

 public static long OverageUnderage(long hours, long counter)
 {
 long overageAmount = 0;
 long overagePercent = 0;

     if (hours < 1760)
     {    
        overageAmount = 1760 - hours;
        overagePercent = ((overageAmount/1760)*100);

        System.out.println("Employee "+counter+" worked "+hours+" hours, an under-run of "+overageAmount+" or "+overagePercent+"%");
    }

    return counter;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number `( overageAmount / 1760 )` is being treated as a long, not a double, which you'll need. Try:

```
overagePercent = ( ( overageAmount / 1760.0 ) * 100 );
```

using the `.0` on 1760 will have it treated as a decmial value.  This will prevent the rounding to 0 issue you were seeing, and allow the calculation to have decimals for the rest of the calculations, providing you with your desired result.

Answer (score 3):

That's why (IMHO) you divide long instead of doubles:

```
overagePercent = ((overageAmount / 1760)*100);
```

Here `overageAmount/1760` returns **0**!
So you have two solutions:

1. First convert `overageAmount` to double and then execute the operation
2. Divide with float `1760.0` so resulting number is already a float

Answer (score 1):

The order you perform the calculations matters, especially for `int` values.

Instead of

```
overagePercent = overageAmount / 1760 * 100;
```

which is likely to be 0 * 100 or 0 you can do

```
overagePercent = overageAmount * 100 / 1760;
```

this could still be 0, but only if the answer is less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get answer in decimals, you have to use double or decimal.
You cant use Long which is for integers.